# CORS does not work MVC6 - RC1

Tags: angularjs, cors, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core

Enabled  CORS in MVC6 app, and Startup looks like:

I added following code in `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
    });
```

......
In configure `Configure()`

```
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
```

.......

My code tries to download angular templates from another url, the templtes get download (saw in fiddler). But my browser console says

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://hsa-is-utl32.[mydomain].com/LayoutService//platform/templates/layout/topbanner.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://mydevbox.[mydomain].com' is therefore not allowed access.

No clue whats wrong??

Comment: You should include more full code which you use. For example it's important **the order** `Configure` of included middleware. I mean `app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");` should be called not too late. Second you should write which version of Angular you use and how `$http` call and `app.config(function($httpProvider) {...}` looks like. One need configure `$http` to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the Ajax request. See `withCredentials: true`, `$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;`, `delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];` and so on.

Comment: Didn't work, my angular config looks like: platform.config(["$provide", "$sceDelegateProvider", "$httpProvider", function ($provide, $sceDelegateProvider, $httpProvider)
{
        
        $provide.constant('rootUrl', rootUrl);      
        $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
            
            'self',            
            'http://*.[domain].com/**',
            'http://*.[domain].gov/**'
        ]);
        
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = true;
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    }]);

Comment: app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin") is the first statment in Configure() method....

Comment: My app download angular directiv js file from another domain and the anngular template file is located along with js file, but when angular tries to download template it generates error.

Comment: You should use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to see HTTP traffic and to see all HTTP headers of the request, which angular sent. If `X-Requested-With` will be set then you should delete it (see above comment).

Comment: No, its not set i saw in fiddler.... if i add "delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];" does not make any difference.

Comment: **You should just append your question with the example of the HTTP request and the corresponding response.** If the HTTP request is correct and it contains `Origin` header then you should verify whether `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` exists in the server response. If request is correct then you should search for the reason in the server code.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Not 100% sure what your setup is like, but maybe this can help. Lets say I have two domains, http://myapp.domain/ where my app sits, and http://templates.domain/template.html where templates are. This is what I did.

This sets up CORS for the MVC 6 app (myapp.domain).

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://myapp.domain").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials());
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
    //make sure its before UseMvc()!!
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I then setup my **`web.config`** file in `wwwroot` of http://templates.domain to allow CORS from http://myapp.domain/. This includes static files like referencing templates in angular from a different domain.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://myapp.domain" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

From then on its simple, lets say for some reason you want to get your route templates from a different domain you can do this:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

    // configure the routes
    app.config(['$provide', '$sceDelegateProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
        function ($provide, $sceDelegateProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

            $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', 'http://templates.domain/**']);
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = true;
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;

            //routes
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'http://templates.domain/template.html',
                controller: 'templatesController'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json, charset=UTF-8'
            };
        }]);

    app.controller('templatesController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'message from controller';
    }]);

})();
```

and in your html its just add `<div ng-view></div>` and include `angular-routes`.

You should now see this in the Response Headers when calling the templates in your angular app.

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://myapp.domain/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment:

     //make sure its before UseMvc()!!

This is important!

Answer (score 1):

Nick's web.config snippet worked for me. I have a similar situation with two applications running on localhost IIS Express. It worked without the app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin") in Startup.cs.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:10001" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest inspecting the headers returned from the MVC applications. Remember if you set AllowCredentials, you cant use Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*.

Try removing the last configuration from MVC app(I mean this one).

```
.AllowCredentials());
```

If you want to set creadentials, I believe you have to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin='URL of the app accessing this site'

You should also inspect the responses with Fiddler and see what is going wrong.

Comment: Removed the .AllowCredentials() part but it didn't work :(